# How to keep Alt+Shift from inadvertently opening the menu bar of the current app on Windows (or how to make ALT purely a modifier key)

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, input-languages, autoit

I'm a long-time Linux user, and a non-native speaker. Just like in Windows, Linux supports the Alt+Shift keyboard combination to switch between input languages. However, its behavior is more forgiving if you mistype and press Alt, followed by Shift, without overlap. On Linux (and  OSX), this results in nothing. On Windows, it detects the lone "Alt" key being pressed, and activates the menu bar of whatever app you're running.

On Windows, this is especially unnerving in a chat application like Skype, when you are frequently switching between languages, and you may not immediately see that you mistyped, Windows selected the menu for you, and the next characters you're typing actually open up some weird menu, or log you out, or inadvertently start a video call. So it's a pet peeve, but it's driving me crazy.

In short, the question boils down to **how do you make Left Alt in Windows to behave purely as a modifier key** (without triggering any action if it is pressed all by itself)?

AutoHotKey or AutoIt hackery is okay. However [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934711/make-autohotkey-ignore-alt-as-menu-key) solution doesn't really work, since it breaks most Alt+*something* shortcuts.

Comment: Check http://superuser.com/a/615424/394258

Comment: @Techie007, the AutoHotKey solution in the answer you linked doesn't work. I've already tried it, as stated in my question.

Comment: Try also this (first of all as standalone script): http://superuser.com/a/1147385/394258

Comment: @user3419297, thank you **so** much. I completely missed that part. After some hacking, I was able to make Windows behave as much like Linux.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: could you please unblock the question, I want to post the script I crafted as an answer. You can rename the question to "Making Windows keyboard shortcuts behave as in Linux"

Comment: I/we appreciate you want to share your solution! If it's a solution to this/the duplicate question, please add your solution to the original question.  If it's the solution to a new question, perhaps make a new question, then answer it.